# Set Focus to DataGridTemplateColumn Child control when pressing enter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `Datagrid` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that has a `TextBox` in it.  When the focus is in the textbox and I press enter to go to the next record it focuses on the `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of the child textbox forcing me to press `Tab` to enter the textbox.  I found this code that works with tabbing into the column that works fabulously, but I can't get the same functionality when I press Enter.

```
<Style x:Key="columnTabStop" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here is my `DataGridTemplateColumn` code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Weld Time" CellStyle="{StaticResource columnTabStop}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.WeldTime,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" 
                 BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="BlanchedAlmond" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I've tried disabling `Focusable` and `IsHitTestVisible` but those aren't what I need.  I've also played with several of the other `KeyboardNavigation` settings but haven't gotten it to work. There's got to be a way of achieving this, but I haven't had any luck finding it.  Basically I want to bypass the `DataGridTemplateColumn` entirely only allowing focus to the child control.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attached property class

```
public class EnterKeyTraversal
{
    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    static void ue_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }

    private static void ue_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ue = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (ue == null) return;

        ue.Unloaded -= ue_Unloaded;
        ue.PreviewKeyDown -= ue_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool),

        typeof(EnterKeyTraversal), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));

    static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ue = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (ue == null) return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            ue.Unloaded += ue_Unloaded;
            ue.PreviewKeyDown += ue_PreviewKeyDown;
        }
        else
        {
            ue.PreviewKeyDown -= ue_PreviewKeyDown;
        }
    }
}
```

and set style for DataGridCell

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="local:EnterKeyTraversal.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
  </Style>
```

Comment: That works awesome Thanks.  I did have to change the `FocusNavigationDirection.Next` to `FocusNavigationDirection.Down` for it to work properly.  It was moving the focus to the right in the same record instead of down to the next record.